# useContext value changes on rerenders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

So I have a component that looks something like

```
const App = () => {
  const someContextValue = useSomeContext();  //custom hook that calls useContext

  useEffect(() => {
    someContextValue()
  }, [someContextValue]);

  return <div />
}
```

Whenever the component rerenders, the useEffect is triggered even though someContextValue hasn't really changed.

I got around this by using useMemo like

`const someContextValue = useMemo(useSomeContext, [useSomeContext])`

Now someContextValue doesn't change on rerenders. But I feel like this isn't quite right. What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: The context value HAS changed. Because the value is defined inside the component and the component is a function. When a function runs, the values that are defined inside it get defined. When you call `useSomeContext()`,  you're creating a new object, and this happens every time the component renders. This is not the same as a state value, where the state value does not get redefined, the `useState` hook maintains the same instance of the value, therefore it is not recreated every time.

Comment: I've added my comment as a more verbose answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're returning an object `{}` or array `[]` from the context, then the context value HAS changed.

The `someContextValue` variable is defined inside the component.

The component is a function, and when a function runs, the values that are defined inside it get defined. If for example, your context returns an object containing state values, then that object is a different instance to the one from the previous render, and your `useEffect` runs because of that.

`useEffect` will compare reference-types by their instance and not the values inside them.

When you call `useSomeContext()`, you're creating a new object, and this happens every time the component renders.

This is not the same as a state value from `useState`, where the state value does not get redefined. The `useState` hook maintains the same instance of the value, therefore it is not recreated every time, and the `useEffect` sees that the state value is the same instance.

This is why, when using context, you should **destructure** the context object and **refererence the values inside** the object, which are either state values passed from a `useState`  hook *inside* the context, or a value defined inside the context that does not get redefined when your consuming component re-renders (because the context does not re-render in that case):

```
const { someStateValue } = useSomeContext()

useEffect(() => {
  someStateValue()
}, [someStateValue]);
```